# Updatepanel inside div is overlapping my css

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a div called "mainContentHolder". In the css I have the height set to auto. In the aspx page I have the following css :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .newPopUpHolder
    {
        display:inline-block;
        width:33px;
    }
    .mainContentHolder label.inlineLbl
    {
        display:inline-block;
        width:70px;
    }
    .mainContentHolder 
    {
        min-width:0px; /* reset */
        width:690px;
    }
</style>
```

then in my main code I have 2 update panels, 1 is filled with 3 radio buttons, and the other update panel with 1 DropDownList. Everything is suppose to appear in a grey box. However, my second UpdatePanel seems to be overlapping the bottom of the grey textbox instead of being inside it. Any ideas as to why?

In my external css, they height property is "height:auto;"

Comment: Do your UpdatePanels have heights set?  What textbox are you talking about?  Can you show your ASPX code?

Comment: posted it. The height is set to auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't matter anymore. I just manually set the height since it won't be changing